# LiveZilla and Prestashop - not displaying on all pages

Tags: prestashop, livechat

I have LiveZilla working on my site, but it's connected to the wrong hook. The chatbar only appears when i click on a menu (horizontal bar) it doesn't appear on homescreen / add to cart page or any other page except links on menu bar.

It only lets me hook it to the 'displayleftcollumn or displayrightcollumn' - when i run live edit i can see the module but its only on the menu pages.

I would like the chatbar to be on every page - I'm using the default bootstrap theme

How do i fix this?

site www.shop.tacitskills.com - click on classroom / online etc, the bar appears.

I have tried asking LiveZilla / Prestashop but no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the module php, and include this to add the option for the footer:

```
public function hookFooter($params)
{
    return $this->hookLeftColumn($params);
}
```

Better yet, create an override file in folder overrides/modules/(modulename)/(modulename).php with

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class (Modulename)Override extends (Modulename)
{
    public function hookFooter($params)
    {
        return $this->hookLeftColumn($params);
    }
}
```

In (modulename) use the livezilla module folder name. 
This way, it will "survive" module updates.
Don't forget to delete the file cache/class_index.php after creating this file.